# magento 2 - Terms and conditions checkbox on register page

Tags: magento-2.1, register, terms-and-conditions

I want to set **terms and conditions checkbox on register**  page which retrieve same as checkout.

On click of **terms and conditions**  link open content in popup.

Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change in following files: 
`/vendor/magento/module-customer/view/frontend/templates/form/register.phtml`
(Append below code)

```
<?php   
     if (!$block->getAgreements()) {
            return;
        }

        /** @var \Magento\CheckoutAgreements\Model\ResourceModel\Agreement\Collection $argeementsCollection */
        $argeementsCollection = $block->getAgreements();
        $agreementMappedArray = [];
        /** @var \Magento\CheckoutAgreements\Model\Agreement $agreement */
        foreach ($argeementsCollection as $agreement) {
            if ($agreement->getIsActive()) {
                $agreementMappedArray[] = [
                    'mode' => $agreement->getMode(),
                    'agreementId' => $agreement->getAgreementId(),
                    'checkboxText' => $agreement->getCheckboxText(),
                    'content' => $agreement->getContent()
                ];
            }
        }
        $agreementJson = json_encode($agreementMappedArray);
        ?>
        <div data-bind="scope: 'checkout-agreements-component-scope'" class="checkout-agreements-block">
        <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
        </div>
```

Add below script :

```
 <script type="text/x-magento-init">
 {
    "*": {
        "Magento_Ui/js/core/app": {
            "components": {
                "checkout-agreements-component-scope": {
                    "component": "Magento_CheckoutAgreements/js/view/checkout-agreements",
                    "agreements": <?php /* @noEscape */ echo $agreementJson; ?>,
                    "isVisible": true
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

> Note : Override form/phtml file into your module, Don't change in core module directly.

Comment: You should never override code files in magento, this is not the way to do anything.

Comment: @Jacta I think you have not read my answer. I mansion same thing in last line as NOTE

Comment: While it may work, there is big downside of this approach, It basically 're-use' same T&Cs that is to be used in checkout page, and could create problem if there is different T&Cs for checkout and registration

Answer (score 1):

These answers might be more fitting if you don't want to fight with bugs:
[Adding a required unchecked check box for Terms and Conditions on new account registration](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/228565/adding-a-required-unchecked-check-box-for-terms-and-conditions-on-new-account-re/)